# Bash shell command that returns the number of lines in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Googleing the subject line returns a lo of commands that tell the file size.  Like:

```
ole@waddup:~/$ du -h package.json 
4.0K    package.json
```

How can we find the number of lines in the file.  For example if `package.json` contains 55 lines, how do we see this very quickly running a command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the wc command line utility:

wc -l package.json

Answer (score 2):

> How can we find the number of lines in the file

```
wc -l <file>
```